# Lazy attribute is null inside transaction after creation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a small example with some get/post mappings and JpaRepository calls in Spring Boot.

Firstly I have two entity Classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends BaseEntity
{
    @Column(name = "value")
    public String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_item")
public class StockItem extends BaseEntity
{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Stock stock;

    @Column(name = "stock_id")
    public Long stockId;

    @Column(name = "value")
    public String value;
}
```

I have a many-to-one association from `StockItem` to `Stock`. 
I insert a `Stock` and have a controller as below:

```java
@Autowired
public Controller(StockItemRepository stockItemRepository) {
    this.stockItemRepository = stockItemRepository;
}

@RequestMapping("/")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public String get() {

    List<StockItem> stockItemList = stockItemRepository.getItemsById(1L);
    System.out.println("TX MANAGER: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

    for (StockItem stockItem : stockItemList) {
        System.out.println(stockItem.getStock().getValue());
    }


    return "get";
}

@RequestMapping("/fromSave")
@Transactional
public String post() {
    StockItem stockItem = new StockItem();
    stockItem.setStockId(1L);
    stockItemRepository.saveAndFlush(stockItem);

    System.out.println("saveCalled");

    return get();
}
```

and `getItemsById` in the repository is defined as follows:

```java
@Query("FROM StockItem si " +
        "JOIN FETCH si.stock stk " +
        "WHERE si.stockId = :id")
List<StockItem> getItemsById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

From my understanding, when I call the post method:

- it creates a new item
- sets the id of the associated attribute
- saves and ends the transaction

Heres where things get strange...
I call get after the post and make the above repository call, which has a join fetch and when I call `stockitem.getStock().getValue()` I get a null pointer when I expect a `LazyInitializationException`.

If I call the `get()` from the mapping, outside the class, it successfully loads the associated object.

I have even removed the `@Transaction` annotation from the get, as well as 
the join-fetch from my query and again, if I call from outside of the class it works and from the post, it crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

I have put the `get` inside of a `TransactionTemplate.execute()` and I still get a `NullPointerException` when calling from inside the class.

So the main questions are:

- Why am I getting a `NullPointerException` instead of `LazyInitializationException`?
- What is the transaction magic behind having no transaction but successfully fetching a lazy attribute??

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are misusing JPA. As you are seemingly aware judging from the comments on the other answer you have mapped the `stock_id` column twice. Once as a many-to-one relationship

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Stock stock;
```

and once as a simple column

```
@Column(name = "stock_id")
public Long stockId;
```

When you set the simple column and flush the changes as in your `post()` method the following happens:

- the value gets set in the simple column. The reference is still `null`.
- the value gets stored in the database. The reference is still `null`.

The repository call will find the id of the `StockItem`in the *Persistence Context* and return that instance, i.e. the exact same used in the post method, with the reference still `null`.

> What is the transaction magic behind having no transaction but successfully fetching a lazy attribute??

No magic involved here. `fetch` specifications are only used for object traversal. JPQL queries don't honor these.

**The unasked question remains: how to fix the situation?**

The obvious fix is to lose the simple column and just use entity references as intended by JPA.

You don't want to do that in order to avoid DB access somewhere. But as long as you only access the `id` of the referenced `Stock` it shouldn't get initialized. So it seems that this should be possible with just *Lazy Fetching*.

Alternatively, I'd suggest removing the many-to-one relationship and creating a repository for `Stock` and manually loading it when required.

Comment: then why is ´Stock´ initialized if I call get() via request mapping vs calling get() from the return of post() ? The fetch join doesnt seem to work in the latter scenario

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_item")
public class StockItem extends BaseEntity
{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) //here is your problem
    public Stock stock;

    @Column(name = "stock_id")
    public Long stockId; // why explicitly define a separate column for foreign key after mapping it above

    @Column(name = "value")
    public String value;
}
```

with `insertable = false` and `updatable = false` it won't insert in your DB and neither it will allow updation, so you are getting `NullPointerException`. You should atleast allow insertion in order to run the query based on the foreign key `stock_id`

**UPDATE**

Change your Entity class with **property-based access**:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_item")
public class StockItem extends BaseEntity
{
    private Stock stock; // variables should always be private since you have getters and setters
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", updatable = false)
    public Stock getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: doing this gives me a "unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory" on building. because this is a repeated column

Comment: Yes you will definitely get that error since you have used field-based access instead of property based access. wait for an update to your answer.

Comment: see my update. Lets see whether your problem gets solved or not

Comment: yes this works however, this is removing the stockID from the entity.. which i need.

Comment: also why does the get() resolve correctly when accessed outside the class vs from an internal call? really looking for an explanation more than an answer

Comment: Kudos.. You can click the Tick Mark to accept this answer as a solution to your question. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: It's an old Bug.

Comment: See this site for more references https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/

Comment: i need to keep the Long id attribute because this cuts down on unnecessary db calls later down the road in my system. I want to keep the entire association entity lazy unless I explicitly need it. So i dont fully feel like you answered my question

Comment: the problem is not with the saving, the saving works. When i debug the id is saved but the problem is with the fetching, why doesnt it fetch correctly?

Comment: also insertable and updatable only deal with including the attribute in insert and update statements